# Is a 2-hour layover at Muscat enough to change flights?

Tags: layovers, mct

I am travelling from Toronto to Delhi. My route is Toronto to London (Air Canada) >> London to Muscat (Oman Air) >> Muscat to Delhi (Oman Air).

I have a 2-hour layover at Muscat before the next flight to Delhi. I'm not sure if this is enough time.

Can someone with experience in this matter share, please?

Comment: As usual, are both flights on the same ticket/booking or not? If not, do you have any checked luggage, and what is your nationality?